# Turn a "protocol with associated type" in to a regular protocol by specifying the type

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have the following protocol:

```
protocol PieceViewGateway {
    subscript(_ identifier: PieceIdentifier) -> UIView {get}
}
```

I make use of this in lots of places in a manner like this:

```
struct SomeKindOfThing {
  let viewGateway: PieceViewGateway
}
```

This is all fine and very nice.

Here's one example of a concrete implementation of the protocol (there are other implementations):

```
struct ViewDictionaryPieceViewGateway: PieceViewGateway {
    let viewDictionary: [PieceIdentifier: UIView]

    subscript(identifier: PieceIdentifier) -> UIView {
        guard let item = viewDictionary[identifier] else { 
          fatalError("Gateway has no value for key: \(identifier)") 
        }

        return item
    }
}
```

I have several protocols like this. Another is `PieceValueGateway` which returns an `Int` instead of a `UIView`.

I'd like to not need to implement something like `ViewDictionaryPieceViewGateway` for the various different "Aspect"s that I need gateways for.

I tried to achieve this by defining a protocol with associated type to model gateways:

```
protocol PieceAspectGateway {
    associatedtype Aspect
    subscript(_ identifier: PieceIdentifier) -> Aspect {get}

}
```

I'd then conform `PieceViewGateway` to this:

```
protocol PieceViewGateway: PieceAspectGateway {
    subscript(_ identifier: PieceIdentifier) -> UIView {get}
}
```

However, this give a lot of compile errors that:

> Protocol 'PieceViewGateway' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

The errors are reported on code *that was fine* before I added the conformance `PieceViewGateway: PieceAspectGateway`. Eg, the `SomeKindOfThing` declaring it has a `let viewGateway: PieceViewGateway`.

I also tried conforming like this:

```
protocol PieceViewGateway: PieceAspectGateway where Aspect == UIView {
    subscript(_ identifier: PuzzlePieceIdentifier) -> UIView {get}
}
```

And like this:

```
protocol PieceViewGateway: PieceAspectGateway {
    typealias Aspect = UIView
    subscript(_ identifier: PuzzlePieceIdentifier) -> UIView {get}
}
```

… but all these variations give the same error whenever `PieceViewGateway` is used as a protocol.

Is there some way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the line with the error in the question? But in general you cannot use `varName: PieceViewGateway ` now, you must declare generic `<T: PieceViewGateway>(varName: T)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `protocol` with `associatedtype` and a type eraser to create any kind of `Gateway`. Please see below,

```
protocol PieceAspectGateway {
    associatedtype Aspect
    subscript(_ identifier: PieceIdentifier) -> Aspect {get}

}

struct AnyGateway<T>: PieceAspectGateway {
    let dictionary: [PieceIdentifier: T]

    subscript(identifier: PieceIdentifier) -> T {
        guard let item = dictionary[identifier] else {
            fatalError("Gateway has no value for key: \(identifier)")
        }
        return item
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
let viewGateway: AnyGateway<UIView>
let viewGateways: [AnyGateway<UIView>] = []

let intGateway: AnyGateway<Int>
let intGateways: [AnyGateway<Int>] = []

let stringGateway: AnyGateway<String>
let stringGateways: [AnyGateway<String>] = []
```

Comment: Hi – thank you. I generally kind of understand why type erasing is needed. In this case I have to say I'm pretty flummoxed. Thank you for the answer though!

Answer (score -1):

What you want to accomplish is quite straightforward:

```
protocol PieceAspectGateway {
    associatedtype Aspect
    subscript(_ identifier: PieceIdentifier) -> Aspect {get}
}
```

so you have this protocol. When you want to inherit from it and use a more specific type, you can use generic constraint:

```
protocol IntPieceAspectGateway: PieceAspectGateway where Aspect == Int {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This will again lead to the same `error` when you will try to declare an `array` like `let a: [IntPieceAspectGateway] = []`

Comment: Of course it will. You have to use a concrete type if you want to use generic collections. There is no way to use a protocol with associated type as generic parameter in Swift. So you have to create a struct or a class which conforms to it

Comment: Yes, but this is what OP already has. He want to find a way not to create `n` number of concrete types.

Comment: I assure you, it doesn't. It was the second thing I tried (after trying the `typealias Aspect = UIView` in `PieceViewGateway`. It doesn't make `PieceViewGateway` a "normal" protocol that you can pass about. It remains a type constraint, as the protocol with associated type `PieceAspectGateway` is.

Comment: @Benjohn When I said it will I was answering to Kamran. Yes I know it will give you the same error without creating a concrete type. In Kamran's answer I don't think there is needed the protocol. This way you can create a base class with a generic parameter, the protocol is just useless as you can declare those methods in the base class.